ETH deposited from coinbase to bybit but not credited
We hope this message finds you well.
We sincerely apologize for the delay in addressing your deposit inquiry. We understand how important your assets are to you and deeply regret any inconvenience this may have caused. Our team is working diligently to assist all affected users as quickly as possible.
To streamline the resolution of unsupported coin deposits, we are pleased to introduce the new Unsupported Coin Deposits Self-Retrieval Feature. This feature allows users to withdraw coins deposited via unsupported methods, subject to specific terms and conditions.
Here’s how you can retrieve your unsupported coin deposits:
Submit a withdrawal request through the Pending Asset page.
For step-by-step guidance, refer to the instructions in How to Recover an Unsupported Deposit.
Important Notes:
This function supports selected token types only.
If you cannot find your asset in your deposit history or the Pending Asset page, please review the following criteria:
Your deposit may be affected by the Deposit/Withdrawal Status of Coins. Set up an alert in the deposit/withdrawal pop-up window for updates.
Bybit only supports deposits for coins listed on our Public Asset Page with specific standard blockchain and contract addresses. Using unsupported coins or chains may lead to irretrievable outcomes.
Unsupported coin deposits are not eligible for recovery if they meet these conditions:
The coin is outside the Top 100 on CoinMarketCap.
The transaction uses blockchains such as KCC, OEC, Ronin, or Cronos, or if the chain is not listed on our Crypto Deposit/Withdrawal Page.
The coins were sent to token contract addresses or have a different contract address than displayed on the Bybit Deposit Window.
If your transaction does not meet the above conditions, please reply to this email with detailed information, including your TXID/Blockchain URL. Recovery will be conducted on a best-effort basis, and while we strive to assist, recovery is not guaranteed for all cases. Please allow 7–15 working days for a reply and avoid submitting duplicate requests.
For more details, please refer to the How to Recover an Unsupported Deposit.
If your issue has already been resolved, you may disregard this email, as your ticket will be automatically closed.
We sincerely appreciate your patience and understanding as we diligently work to address all inquiries. Thank you for choosing Bybit.
With warmest regards

Please the above is the email i got from bybit after submitting a request concerning my ETH that was sent from Coinbase to bybit account but it was moved to bybit hot wallet, now this is the message i got from bybit please can anyone guide me on what i neeɗ to submit to get them retrieve my ETH back?

I’m voting to close this question because this is a support question for ByBit customer service, not to a general public discussion forum where anyone could help you

Ok I've submitted the valid information and I'm waiting for a positive feedback  and give me back my ETH
